# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf, office-interop

I am trying to convert docx file into pdf and I have been successful to convert pdf on my local pc.

Steps which i have followed in `visual studio 2010` is to

```
click on Add reference --> Click to COM -->select "Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library" and cliked ok
```

My web config gets modified and added the assembly

```
<add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/>
```

My .cs code for converting doc to pdf is

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;//Name Space


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)//Coading on page load
{

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(Server.MapPath("~/convert/goodquest.docx"));
    wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(Server.MapPath("~/convert/goodquest.pdf"), WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
}

public Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDocument { get; set; }
```

All `works fine in local` but when i `upload` all this changes on `web`.

Errors such as

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

are showing up.
How should i resolve this problem

I have also tried downloading "Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies Redistributable" from link [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=3508) but it converted my "Version=12.0.0.0" to "Version=14.0.0.0" when i follow steps which i have told you about before as " click on Add reference --> Click to COM........"

Comment: I have update my answer, please now take a look there

Comment: i have added Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll intp bin folder which i have get from http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=3508 now the error such as "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'" is coming

Comment: You have missed the correct version, please check that

Comment: I assume you understand that you need Office installed (and properly licensed) on server. Note that running Office applications in ASP.Net servers is not supported- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757.

Comment: ok now downloading from this link http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=18346

Comment: i have installed 2007 Microsoft Office System Update and my version changed to version 14.0

Comment: can any one provide me a correct version link of Version=12.0.0.0, so that i download it and add .dll to bin

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: How do you deploy your office interop dlls? With MSI? I know that msi is evil and it contains hard coded strategies to replace the to be installed office interop.dll with a different version. Since then the Azure guys have switched to xcopy deployment and custom hooks instead of msi ;-).

Comment: same problem is .. working on localhost but when i am uploading it online then getting same problem

Answer (score 3):

Copy paste the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll` into bin folder in server.

It's may be added in this path

`%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\`
but i don't know is it correct : more details please see this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx) Link

else, You can download this dll : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6309218/2218635

Comment: from where should i get? can you provide me the link?

Comment: i have added Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll intp bin folder which i have get from http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=3508 now the error such  as "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'" is coming

Comment: i have installed 2007 Microsoft Office System Update and my version changed to version 14.0

Comment: @RonakBhatt can you provide a correct version link of 12.0,as I am also not getting that link. same issue is held with me i have downloaded and it converts them to 14.0

Comment: @RameshRajendran can you provide a correct version link of 12.0,as I am also not getting that link. same issue is held with me i have downloaded and it converts them to 14.0

Comment: @RameshRajendran please have look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274953/convert-of-word-file-docx-doc-to-pdf-using-c-sharp-is-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Have you copied DLL (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word) to the executable path?

you have to copy this DLL to local path else the Microsoft office must be installed on this server.

Looking into error it seems that application is not able to find the file in specified path.

By default application will find the DLL first into GAC else into local path. There can be other reason like the version is different, in such case also you will get similar error.

Comment: i have installed 2007 Microsoft Office System Update and my version changed to version 14.0

Comment: Ok so in that case you should have exact same DLL version present as your local machine to make it work. Please either install same office version or you can keep same DLL at local path and remove DLL from GAC if there any this should also work.

Comment: @Nil23 can you provide a correct version link of 12.0,as I am also not getting that link. same issue is held with me i have downloaded and it conerts them to 14.0

Comment: @Nil23 please have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274953/convert-of-word-file-docx-doc-to-pdf-using-c-sharp-is-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the dell version.

Please download correct version of the dll.

Comment: can you provide me a correct version link of 12.0, I am not getting that link

Comment: please have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274953/convert-of-word-file-docx-doc-to-pdf-using-c-sharp-is-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Correct procedure to use Word in C# Projects is:

1. Add reference to Word Interop Library(Assembly)
2. Add Excel in `using` section
3. Now use it in your coding.

---

---

The first step will work if you have Office(Word) Installed in your PC. If not then install. Then add reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` of the version you need.

a. If list doesn't shows the desire version then you may have another vision of Office with Word installed. By The Way, you can use any.

b. If you don't find anything like `Microsoft.Office.Interop` THEN may be office not installed OR you have Office 2013 or later. For higher version you can add assembly by going into **COM** tab of add-reference windows and add `Microsoft Word {version-no} Object Library`. This will add the same.

c. If you already have `Microsoft.Office.Interop...` in References with yellow-triangle-mark THEN remove it first.

---

---

After that second step will totally work: `using Word=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;`

---

---

And finally as a third step you can create Word object by `Word.Application wApp = new Word.Application();`.