# Convert of word file(.docx & doc) to .pdf using c# is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, ms-word

I am using visualstudio 2010 and I am trying to convert word.docx file to .pdf file and is working fine in local but on run time on server it is showing error as

```
Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

What I have tried is added reference and put in bin folder

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.xml
```

as shown in figure

[image]

my .cs code is as

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

 wordApp.Visible = false;

            // file from
 object filename =Server.MapPath("word.docx"); // input

    // file to
 object newFileName = Server.MapPath("pdf/document_to_read_tomorrow.pdf"); // output
 object missing = System.Type.Missing;

            // open document
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            // formt to save the file, this case PDF
 object formatoArquivo = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;

            // changes in paper size

 doc.PageSetup.PaperSize = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPaperSize.wdPaperA4;

            // changes orietation paper
 doc.PageSetup.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdOrientation.wdOrientPortrait;

            // other changes
 doc.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 20;
 doc.PageSetup.RightMargin = 0;


            // save file
 doc.SaveAs(ref newFileName, ref formatoArquivo, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

 doc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

 wordApp.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

My WebConfig seems as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="xyz" connectionString="Data Source=xyz;Initial Catalog=xyz;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xyz;Password=xyz" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha"/>
        <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/></assemblies>
        <buildProviders>
            <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="Off">
    </customErrors>
    <sessionState timeout="720">
    </sessionState>
    <pages enableViewStateMac="false"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear/>
            <add value="default.aspx"/>
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
        <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended to use the Office interop in a server environment due to the memory leaks and perfomance issues. You will have to look for a managed solution to convert PDF to word in a server, than installing the office package and the interop assemblies there. There are a few managed components which can get the work done, but they are not free.

http://www.aspose.com/.net/pdf-component.aspx
http://www.websupergoo.com/wordglue-1.htm

Comment: my application  has no need for security and has no issue to have been fast process, i just want the work to be done for free, sorry but its the requirement of my client

Comment: @MiteshJain did the client *buy* one Office license for every user? If not, you can't use Office interop, end of story.

Answer (score 2):

I had long been looking for a solution to these issues and in the end I had to use a third party. I suggest you use a third party like Aspose
[Aspose.Total for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/.net/total-component.aspx)

> Aspose.Words for .NET is an advanced class library for .NET that enables you to perform a wide range of document processing tasks directly within your .NET applications.
>
> With Aspose.Words you can generate, modify, convert, render and print
>   documents without using Microsoft Word.
>
> Aspose.Words for .NET supports DOC, OOXML, RTF, HTML, OpenDocument,
>   PDF, XPS, EPUB and many other formats.

This component work perfectly for me and very simple to use.
this is an example of convert word to pdf code :

```
Document doc = new Document(getMyDir() + "Document.doc");
doc.save(getMyDir() + "Document.Doc2PdfSave Out.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the "office.dll" library in the Global Assembly Cache on the server too to make this work. Check out the C:\Windows\assembly folder and you will find office.dll there.

EDIT:
It seems that this will not be as simple as it looks. Some developers mention [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/585f86b2-c109-4dc0-aaff-a474d28e24c9/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftofficeinteropexcel?forum=netfxbcl) that Office would have to be installed on the server or you will need to install even more libraries manually.

Comment: i have found office msil in assembly folder

Comment: If it is simple than running Office apps would be supported on servers... But it is not, so everyone trying it are on they own.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov is there not an any easy way

Comment: I'm afraid there is nothing easier than installing Office on the server or finding a alternative library that can achieve what you need. Both are however quite hard...

Comment: How shall I install office on server?

Comment: You shall not... But steps are easy - buy license, install, hope it would work for your case. Obviously there is no guarantees that it will work at all under your Web server's account or will not require effort to get at least something out of it... But since *your* work is free I see no problem you spending a lot of time on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this now with C# in NET Core easily with LibreOffice. Here's a [small writeup](https://www.debugandrelease.com/how-to-convert-docx-files-to-pdf/) on it and a link to a working self-contained solution; but the code is below.

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConvertDOCXToPDF
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create LibreOfficeWriter CLI process
            var commandArgs = new List<string>
            {
                "--convert-to", //a flag that will be followed by the file type we want to convert to
                "pdf:writer_pdf_Export", // the [output file type]:[OutputFilterName] we are requesting the output to be; more details are here (https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/guide/convertfilters.html)
                "C:\\Users\\zachary\\Downloads\\Letter.docx", // input file
                "--norestore", // disables restart and file recovery after a system crash
                "--headless", // allows using the application without user interface
                "--outdir", // a flag that will be followed by the output directory where we want our new pdf file to be created
                "C:\\Users\\zachary\\Downloads" // output directory
            };

            // The path to LibreOfficeWriterPortable.exe
            ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Users\\zachary\\Downloads\\LibreOfficePortablePrevious\\LibreOfficeWriterPortable.exe"); 
            foreach (string arg in commandArgs)
                processStartInfo.ArgumentList.Add(arg);

            Process process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = processStartInfo
            };

            // Only 1 instance of LibreOfficeWriter can be running at a given time
            Process[] existingProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("soffice");
            while (existingProcesses.Length > 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                existingProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("soffice");
            }

            // Start the process
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();

            // Check for failed exit code.
            if (process.ExitCode != 0)
                throw new Exception("Failed to convert file");
            else
            {
                int totalChecks = 10;
                int currentCheck = 1;

                string originalFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(commandArgs[2]);
                string newFilePath = Path.Combine(commandArgs[6], $"{originalFileName}.pdf");

                while (currentCheck <= totalChecks)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(newFilePath))
                    {
                        // File conversion was successful

                        break;
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(500); // LibreOffice doesn't immediately create PDF output once the command is run
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```