# Send emails through any version of Outlook

Tags: c#, email, outlook

My program sends email through the 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook' assembly.
The problem is that in my client's PCs the Outlook version is different and I get this exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook, Version=15.0.0.0

How can I solve it so that it could send emails through any version of Outlook?

Comment: A basic solution I am providing is : Copy paste the Microsoft.Office.Interop.outlook.dll into bin path.I think the client does not have Microsoft.Office.Interop.* in bin path installed.Not tested! From:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866895/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-office-interop-word-version-12-0-0-0

Comment: [*Any Version*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Outlook)? What is, realistically, the set of versions you need to support? (I can accept an open ended upper range, but seriously doubt you need code that works with Outlook 97)

Comment: Is the sending via Outlook mandatory? Did you think about using SmtpClient.Send?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever versions are between 2010 and 2016.

Comment: @Rene no internet on those pcs so mandatory it is.

Comment: What do you mean with "no internet on the client"? If the Clients can't access a SMTP Server, Outlook will not be able to send mails either, no?

Comment: @Rene when thinking about it you are right, they can send me emails so they have internet. In that case, I guess I need to ask the admin for credentials to use SmtpClient?

Comment: At least you will need the SMTP serveradress, which you might find in your Outlook settings. ;-) Otherwise you are right: Ask the Admin for the correct credentials.

Comment: Regarding the 'send via SMTP' comments, all fine until the users start complaining that their Outlook signatures aren't on the emails, or they don't have a record in their Sent Items folder. Pumping them through Outlook gets you a lot of things like the above, and failed send handling etc that you'd have to implement yourself via SMTP.

Answer (score 1):

Develop with an interop with the lowest version of Outlook that you plan to support (2010?) and mark your reference as version independent.

Comment: Can you please describe how do I mark the reference as version independent?

Comment: Select Outlook interop in your project references, make sure "Specific Version" is set to False.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by:
Remove the nugget, but add Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library COM reference instead and set AddTrue </ EmbedInteropTypes >

Comment: What does Excel interop have to do with Outlook?

Comment: Thanks for picking this up. Outlook of course. Edited.