# Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.Office, Version=2.1.0.0,'

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, office-interop, asp.net-3.5

I'm using .NET version 3.5, while i'm uploading data into Oracle database from .xls files using C#.NET
getting below error:

> Exception  System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>
> Error Message Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.Office,
> Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file.
>
> Stacktrace
>
> at FileHelpers.DataLink.ExcelStorage.CloseAndCleanUp() at
> FileHelpers.DataLink.ExcelStorage.ExtractRecords() at "......"

i have tried with `interop.office version=2.1.0.0` .dll, even getting same error.

Comment: Some time ago, I also had to work with Excel sheets but I gave up. I ended in a 3rd party library like https://docs.aspose.com/cells/net/ or https://www.grapecity.com/componentone/docs/win/online-excel/overview.html

Comment: Thanks for your commentes , but i'm not getting any error in my local system, i'm getting this error after deployed publish code in server "Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard (64-bit)".

Comment: What are the MS-Office versions, i.e. do have 32-bit MS-Office on your local machine and 64-bit MS-Office on the server (or vice versa)? You need to compile your application at the same architecture (i.e. 32/64 bit) as the installed Office at target machine.

Comment: My local system and server both are 32 bit MS Office installed and version also same "Office version=15.0.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

> Exception System.IO.FileNotFoundException

> Error Message Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.Office, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file.

The exception says that the Interop.Office.dll file is missing on the computer. You need to include it to the installer.

However, Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

Consider using third-party components designed for the server-side execution. Also if you consider dealing with open XML spreadsheets (.xslx) you may also consider using the Open XML SDK, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your post, but i'm getting this error in client server they are using "Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard (64-bit)", i'm not geeting any error in my local system as well as in my server after deployed code.

Comment: That is exactly your case. You may not trap into issues on your side, but other systems can be faulty.

Comment: do have any idea on this? what i'm missing on this case. am misssing some dll references?

Comment: The error message says that an assembly is absent. Try to include the missed assembly to the installer. But you really need to avoid using Office on the server-side.

Comment: i have added both  DLL  in my Web application bin folder   "Interop.Excel.dll version=2.1.0.0 and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll version=15.0.0.4569.1506 " even i'm getting same error, i don't know what am i missing.

Comment: The error is for the `interop.office.dll` assembly.

Comment: tried adding "Interop.Office.dll" getting below error "Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.Office, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

Comment: Yes, you need to include that assembly to your installer. According to your comment above you have included  "Interop.Excel.dll version=2.1.0.0 and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll version=15.0.0.4569.1506 ", but not `Interop.Office.dll`.

Comment: I need to add in "C:\Windows\assembly" folder ?

Comment: To the same place with your application.

Comment: if you are talking about Project/bin folder i have already added after that i got  manifest defination error.

Comment: You need to build your solution with a reference to the office.dll assembly, a corresponding interop will be added as a dependency automatically when you build the installer. Try to get it that way.

Comment: yes i have added and build the solution and publish the code same is working fine in my side not working on client server same code we have deployed in client server.

Comment: Does it work correctly on the client machine, not server-side?

Comment: Actually I'm published the code and deployed server machine at my end working fine, same code i have deployed in client machine getting above error.

Comment: You can find a lot of similar questions posted over the internet and they all suggests the same that I wrote here, see [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866895/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-office-interop-word-version-12-0-0-0).

Comment: still i can't found  proper solution on this issue, now i used alternative solution for this.